# python set handling for superset calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have three inputs now,

```
combs_dict = {frozenset({'time'}): '0', frozenset({'rfid'}): '0', frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}): '0', frozenset({'zone', 'rfid'}): '0', frozenset(): '0', frozenset({'zone', 'time'}): '0', frozenset({'zone'}): '0'}

prob_dict = {'2': '0.5', '4': '0.05', '3': '0.3', '1': '0.15'}

map_dict = {'2': {frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}), frozenset({'zone', 'time'})}, '4': {frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'})}, '1': {frozenset({'zone', 'time'})}, '3': {frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}), frozenset({'rfid', 'zone'})}}
```

I am trying to compare combs_dict with map_dict. If any key in combs_dict is a super set(>=) of any element in the values of map_dict, then i have to add corresponding prob for that key from prob_dict to the value of combs_dict.

For example, if i am taking frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}) from combs_dict and comparing with values in map_dict and find that it is a superset of this {'2': {frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}), frozenset({'zone', 'time'})} and this '3': {frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}), since because they both have its equivalent or subset. I will have to get the probability of its key 2 and 3 from prob_dict and sum it up with the value in combs_dict like this (frozenset({'rfid', 'time'}): '0'+'0.5+'0.05').

What i have tried now is this,

```
for k,v in combs.items():
    for ky,values in map_output.items():
        if any(k>=l for l in values):
            v = v + (j for i,j in prob.items() if i == ky)
```

But i am not able to add the probabilities in 'v' since j is returned as a generator. Can some one help on this. Is there any option to parallelize this using multiprocessing? Because i will be having nearly 50k frozensets in comb_dict, so i have to compare each of that frozenset with every element in map_ouput.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. I will explain.

Comment: `v = v + sum((j for i,j in prob.items() if i == ky))` ?

Comment: Cool. But why i am not getting combs_dict updated ? when i print it after this step. I am still getting all sets with value 0... :(

Comment: then `combs[k] += sum((j for i,j in prob.items() if i == ky))` to update the dictionary (you are currently updating an integer value, not a reference to the value object in the dictionary)... you can also simplify the outer loop to `for k in combs.keys()` in that case.

Comment: Awesome.. It works.. Thanks.. :) But is there a way to parallelize it or make it anymore efficient, because as i said above, i am going to execute this for a big dataset. Two for loops and comparison with each element looks to me a bit dangerous..